# Can you explain the behavior of PHP in cases when a parent class variable is masked by the child variable of the same name?

Tags: php, language-features, parameters, initialization, binding

See the comment inside `ChildEntity ::__construct()`:

```
class ChildEntity extends ParentEntity
{
    /** @var int */
    protected $classParameter;

    function __construct(int $classParameter)
    {
        /**
         * Question
         *
         * Below are the two ways of initializing the variable of ChildEntity
         *
         * Are they both initializing the same child(?) variable?
         * Are they initializing the parent(?) variable?
         * Can the child and parent have different values at the same time,
         * perhaps in different contexts?
         */
        $this->classParameter = $classParameter; // init local(?) variable?
        parent::__construct($classParameter); // init parent(?) variable?
    }
}

class ParentEntity
{
    /** @var int */
    protected $classParameter;

    function __construct(int $classParameter)
    {
        $this->classParameter = $classParameter;
    }
}

$childEntity = new ChildEntity(100);
```

Why does the below work (slightly different code - parameter removed in parent, and child uses only parent constructor to initialize).  It looks like the parent class manipulates a variable found in the child class, without that variable being present in parent.  It is as if the variable in `ChildEntity` and `ParentEntity` become one, and the child and parent instances also serve as a single instance, for all intents and purposes.  Is that what actually happens behind the scenes?

```
class ChildEntity extends ParentEntity
{
    /** @var int */
    protected $classParameter;

    function __construct(int $classParameter)
    {
        parent::__construct($classParameter); 
        print $this->classParameter;
    }
}

class ParentEntity
{
    function __construct(int $classParameter)
    {
        $this->classParameter = $classParameter;
    }
}

$childEntity = new ChildEntity(5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are they both initializing the same child(?) variable?

When the object is created, all the non-private properties of all parent classes belong to this newly created object. He doesn't know which properties belong to class it was created with, and which ones belong to a parent one.

> Can the child and parent have different values at the same time, perhaps in different contexts?

Only if you create two different objects, like that (I added a getter method):

```
$childEntity = new ChildEntity(5);
var_dump($childEntity->getClassParameter());

$parentEntity = new ParentEntity(6);
var_dump($parentEntity->getClassParameter());
```

> Why does the below work?

When you write the following code:

```
class ParentEntity
{
    function __construct(int $classParameter)
    {
        $this->classParameter = $classParameter;
    }
}
```

that is, you initialize a property in a constructor without declaring it, php internally declares it itself. And when you create a `ChildEntity`, everything happens exactly the same as I already described. I should mention that php assigns this undeclared property a `public` visibility -- despite of, however crazy, it contradicts [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://hackernoon.com/liskov-substitution-principle-a982551d584a). Check it out:

```
class ChildEntity extends ParentEntity
{
    /** @var int */
    protected $classParameter;

    function __construct(int $classParameter)
    {
        parent::__construct($classParameter);
        var_dump($this->classParameter);
    }

    public function getClassParameter()
    {
        return $this->classParameter;
    }
}

class ParentEntity
{
    function __construct(int $classParameter)
    {
        $this->classParameter = $classParameter;
    }
}

$parentEntity = new ParentEntity(6);
var_dump($parentEntity->classParameter);

$childEntity = new ChildEntity(5);
var_dump($childEntity->classParameter); // oops, an error!
```

Comment: hmm so there is a way to trick PHP into breaking LSP .....

Comment: @Zapadlo That's a bad breach of LSP, wasn't aware of this one until now, thanks

Comment: php is full of surprises :)